# Update data of few columns from one table to another using cursors

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to update data from one table to another using a cursor.The cursor should update data from one table to another on the basis of id but if the data is not found then inserts the row in the database.Can anyone help me with examples

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: i made a cursor from the table data is to be updated @getdata with the column fields that need to be updated on the basis of customer id if exists then update else insert into the table